# iText Sharp 7 License error {"Licensee element was not found."}

Tags: itext7

I am using iText Sharp 7 HTML2PDF for POC development to generate. HTML from PDF.

I have imported iText following for my development POC from Nuget

1. itext7.7.0.2.2
2. itext7.pdfhtml.1.0.0.2
3. itext7.licensekey.2.0.3

I have also referred reference manuals(.NET) from http://developers.itextpdf.com/license-key-download and instructions from the iTextSharp site but still I am getting a license error from my .NET Code:

```
{"Licensee element was not found."}
```

Code:

```
iText.License.LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(@"D:\AmitGera\Projects\LatestCode\23052017\packages\itext7.licensekey.2.0.3\lib\net40\itext.licensekey.xml");
```

I request you to please suggest regarding license issues.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the outdated license key instructions on the iText website.

Comment: Hello Amedee can you please tell how issue can be solved? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello itext guys help me in this context as I am stuck due it.A quick input will be a great help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a suitable venue for licensing support questions. These should be directed to a third party software provider.

Comment: Agreed, and that's exactly what the vendor asked. (Joris and myself are employees of said vendor) Stack Overflow should only be used for questions about how to use our product, as described in the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Please use our support system for these questions. It allows you to confidentially share your license key (which you can't do here). By sharing your key, we can check if everything is ok.

If you do not have a support contract, please contact your iText sales representative for licensing issues.

Comment: It means I need to have purchase before checking whether it will fit in my requirements? . I have downloaded itext 7 packages from Nuget to do POC for our requirements! Do itext have concept of evaluation version or temp license key so that we can validate if fit to our requirement . Please suggest

Comment: No, it means that if you're planning on using this product commercially (even if you're only using it to develop a POC application) you can already make use of our support services ;-)